# Como recargar un iframe cuando se presione un boton en Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, iframe

quiero que un iframe con una url se vuelva a recargar cuando se presione un menu del tabs inferior en ionic ¿como se haría?

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
<iframe id="homei" src="http://mipagina.com/posts" frameborder=0 style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Quiero que ese iframe se vuelva a cargar cuando se presione un boton en el tabs

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="home" tabIcon="home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="info" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

estoy trabajado con Ionic

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.2.1
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v8.12.0
npm    : 6.4.1
OS     : Windows 7
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que al presionar alguno de los botones de abajo se vuelva a cargar el iframe con la pagina

Comment: recargar el mismo url o cambiarlo según el tab?

Comment: cambiarlo según el tab